# How to make Python chart that only contain Vertical and horizontal Lines?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to draw something like this?
There's kind of like a horizontal line until next data point show up, then a vertical line to adjust the location y. The usual plot function in matplotlib just plot a straight line between two data point, which doesn't satisfy what I need.

[image: The example screenshot]

Comment: Just add another point into your dataset such that for every changing Y coordinate, add the previous Y coordinate with the new X coordinate

Comment: @cricket_007 I have came up with that solution too. Though your answer isn't what I am really asking for, thanks anyway. It's my fault not making my question clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use one of the drawstyles `"steps-pre"`, `"steps-mid"`, `"steps-post"` to get a a step-like appearance of your curve.

```
plt.plot(x,y, drawstyle="steps-pre")
```

Full example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed()

x = np.arange(12)
y = np.random.rand(12)

styles = ["default","steps-pre","steps-mid", "steps-post"]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(styles), figsize=(4,7))

for ax, style in zip(axes, styles):
    ax.plot(x,y, drawstyle=style)
    ax.set_title("drawstyle={}".format(style))

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I am looking for ! Thanks, matplotlib pro.

Answer (score 0):

Just as @cricket_007 said in the comments -- make each y value repeat at the next x value. Below a way how to achieve this with `numpy`.

**EDIT**:

Thanks to the comment by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I replaced the original code that extended the data with a much simpler solution.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#producing some sample data
x = np.linspace(0,1,20)
y = np.random.rand(x.shape[0])

#extending data to repeat each y value at the next x value  
##x1 = np.zeros(2*x.shape[0]-1)
##x1[::2] = x
##x1[1::2] = x[1:]
x1 = np.repeat(x,2)[1:]

##y1 = np.zeros(2*y.shape[0]-1)
##y1[::2] = y
##y1[1::2] = y[:-1]
y1 = np.repeat(y,2)[:-1]

plt.plot(x1, y1)    
plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:

[image: result of the code above]

Comment: Yes, in two lines: `x1 = np.repeat(x,2)[:-1];
y1 = np.repeat(y,2)[1:]`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for the hint. Despite the fact that your answer is the better one anyway, I took the freedom to add these two lines to my code (except for switching the indexing, as I wanted what in your solution would be `steps_post`).

Comment: @Thomas Kühn I have learned some numpy method from you. Thank you for your help!